# Pandas Dataframe unable to reference column name in Plotly Dash Dropdown when set to reference in google sheets column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, plotly-dash

I am currently busy with a Plotly Dash Web Application and busy creating a dropdown referencing a column from a pandas dataframe I am reading in from a CSV file.

The issue is it is not able to read the column and I have seen it is because the column is actually a reference of another sheet I.e =RawData!A1.

I have managed to print the column so I know it exists in the dataframe and all the data is printing correctly however, Plotly Dash does not want to populate the dropdown with the label and values - my current line of code is:

```
options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.CategoryName.unique()],
```

Category name in Google Sheets is referring to =RawData!A1

What I have tested:

1. Ammended my sheet name to read directly from my RawData sheet and it works fine - This is not a solution that I want though, this lead me to see the issue was with the reading from the referenced column.
2. Attempted using column index instead:

```
options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.iloc[:,1].unique()],
```

Again this worked for printing but not to populate the dropdown in plotly dash.

Any advise will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So by actually adding some data cleaning to remove rows at the bottom of my dataset in pandas it fixed my issue.

I added a remove nan based on my column CategoryName and by doing that my dropdown worked

```
df = df[df['CategoryName'].notna()]
```

The reason it worked makes sense - I setup my copy form to =RawData!A:A so my RawData at the moment only comprising of 123 rows, by row 125 in my reference sheet it was referencing a blank column causing the dropdown to have an error showing a reference to something that does not exist, very funny error but logical at the same time. Not sure if this will help many people but hopefully it will assist somebody!